# Value cannot be null. Parameter name: control

Tags: asp.net, ajax, listview, asp.net-ajax, registerstartupscript

I used to have the UpdatePanel as a wrapper for the whole Listview item.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server">
            <LayoutTemplate>
                <asp:PlaceHolder id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
            </LayoutTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate> 
                '....
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
    </ContentTemplate>
 <Triggers></Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

and register the client script as follows...

```
 Private Sub ListView1_ItemCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewCommandEventArgs) Handles ListView1.ItemCommand
    if Not ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(Me.[GetType](), "OtherScript") Then
       ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(DirectCast(Page.FindControl("UpdatePanel1"), UpdatePanel), GetType(String), "alertScript", "update('hpClips','false','inc')", True)
    End If
 End sub
```

Now i decided to wrap only the group of ImageButtons with update panels as follows...

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <asp:PlaceHolder id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate> 
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always" RenderMode="Block">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="btnAttach" runat="server" CommandName='<%# "AddC_" & Eval("QID") & "_" & Eval("Label") %>'/>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="btnFavorite" runat="server" CommandName='<%# "AddF_" & Eval("QID")  & "_" & Eval("Label") %>'/>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

and i get the following error

```
Value cannot be null. Parameter name: control
```

while executing 
`ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(DirectCast(Page.FindControl("UpdatePanel1"), UpdatePanel), GetType(String), "alertScript", "update('hpClips','false','inc')", True)`

I think this has to do with the fact that the updatepanel control was not found. And the Direct cast throws the exception. So how could i fix that?
Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE: I tried this one too. (This time, i get no exception but the client script is not executed)**

```
Private Sub ListView1_ItemCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewCommandEventArgs) Handles ListView1.ItemCommand
    Dim UpdPanel As New UpdatePanel
    For Each Up As UpdatePanel In e.Item.Controls.OfType(Of UpdatePanel)()
           UpdPanel = Up             
    Next

    if Not ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(Me.[GetType](), "OtherScript") Then
       ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(DirectCast(UpdPanel, UpdatePanel), GetType(String), "alertScript", "update('hpClips','false','inc')", True)
    End If
End sub
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3399441/value-cannot-be-null-parameter-name-control

Comment: @Jani Pardon me? I do not quite understand, why is that related to my question

Comment: By that I meant that it's a general error like the `object reference not set to an instance of object`, Check the visual studio to catch every exception take a look at the call stack of where the exception was thrown, see the locals and autos, chances are you can find the solution this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed! The following does the trick

```
If Not ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(Me.[GetType](), "OtherScript") Then
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me.Page, Me.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid.ToString, "update('hpClips','false','inc')", True)
End If
```

Resources that helped

[Problem with ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript in WebControl nested in UpdatePanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802506/problem-with-scriptmanager-registerstartupscript-in-webcontrol-nested-in-updatepa)

[Add JavaScript programmatically using RegisterStartupScript during an Asynchronous postback](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=200)